# Test if List of Dates against condition

Tags: excel, powerquery

i have an embedded Table (see screenshot) and want to check if *any* of the values in a Date column is below a certain date...

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfAVF.png)

= Table.AddColumn(Source, "Called NovDec", each List.AnyTrue( { [MD_call_Data][Date] < 1/1/2023 } ) )

in the formula in screenshot i get error..." we cannot apply operator < to types List and Number", what would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can't use < with dates, so convert them first with Number.From()
- 1/1/2023 is not a valid date format, you have to write it as #date(2023,1,1)
- You cant compare a list to a number such as [MD_call_Data][Date] < 100, you have to compare each item in the list with List.Transform

All that said, you can use:

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Called NovDec",  each  List.AnyTrue(List.Transform([MD_call_Data][Date], each Number.From(_)<Number.From(#date(2023,1,1))))),
```

Comment: i finally figured it out and was just about to post so others can use it and I saw yours... thanks for response!